# delete records using gridview ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am writing to seek help in regards deleting database record using checkbox gridview controls.

I am trying to delete the records from “ViewData” using checkbox and gridview but the ‘if’ condition keeps failing.  Any further assistance as to where I may be going wrong would be very much appreciated.  Thank you very much for your time and feedback.

```
//Method for Deleting Record  
protected void DeleteRecord(int ID)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("delete from tbl_Users where ID=@ID", con);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
    con.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}

protected void btnDeleteRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow grow in ViewDataGrid.Rows)
    {
//Searching CheckBox("chkDel") in an individual row of Grid  
CheckBox chkdel = (CheckBox)grow.FindControl("chkDel");
//If CheckBox is checked than delete the record with particular empid  
if (chkdel.Checked)
{
    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(grow.Cells[1].Text);
    DeleteRecord(ID);
}
    }
    //Displaying the Data in GridView  
    showData();
}
```

Error: Input string was not in the correct format in:
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(grow.Cells[1].Text);

Comment: Whatever is in `grow.Cells[1]` cannot convert to an `int`. What is in that cell?

Comment: What is grow.Cells[1].Text?

Comment: According to your question helped me tremendously, I did not put the ID cell in the table! mercy :)

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

In following line

int ID = Convert.ToInt32(grow.Cells[1].Text);

The actual value of grow.Cells[1].Text might be containing alphabetic characters or the whitespace so you are getting this error.

Convert.ToInt32(stringVal) actually converts the specified string representation of a number to an equivalent 32-bit signed integer but the parameter should be a string that contains the number only.

Answer (score 0):

With your select query in the line 
string SelectQuery = "SELECT FROM tbl_Users WHERE ID=" + ID;
you are missing the values you are selecting.

You will either have to select the specific columns required are input * to select all columns. 
e.g. string SelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Users WHERE ID=" + ID;
or
string SelectQuery = "SELECT column1,column3 FROM tbl_Users WHERE ID=" + ID;